# Getting the funk guitar sound from Funkytown

Tags: guitar, sound-effects

One of the sounds that fascinates me the most is [the guitar in Lipps Inc.'s 1980's disco track *Funkytown*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRDc31Co8sI&feature=player_detailpage#t=67s).

The features I like about it are its attack and super rich mid-range.

Any ideas on how it's done and/or how to recreate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Funkytown guitar sound came from a Schecter Strat rented from Knute Koupe in Minneapolis. It was played by Tom Riopelle from the band Fairchild. David Rivkin was the engineer and Steven Greenberg the producer. It was recorded at Sound 80 in Mpls, Studio 2 - where Dylan recorded Blood On The Tracks. Many people have asked about the sound but we want to keep it a secret. We can tell you this...it was achieved with hard work and experimentation NOT taken from a bank of sounds. Ha!

Answer (score 1):

This is a sound design forum, we're mostly here to answer and ask questions about sound in relation to film,tv,games,radio,etc. You are welcome to do so as well, but questions about Funky guitar sound seem more appropriate for a guitar or funk forum I think.

Good luck finding your answer

Arnoud

Answer (score 0):

Arnoud is right but I can tell you this much...

it's a double tracked clean tone stratocaster.  probably played by David Rivkin.